# loc. on Pandas Multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I am trying to make three conditions with & and I am not getting any results although that there is data that meets the conditions. (I am not getting any syntax error)

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
# 2 condition that works perfectly ok:
df.loc[(df['HP'] >= 100) & (df['Type 1'] == "Fire")]

# 3 condition that not works:
df.loc[(df['HP'] >= 80) & (df['Type 1'] == "Fire") & (df['Type 2'] == "NaN")]
```

Comment: Is it possible that last condition should be `df['Type 2'].isna()` and not searching for the word `"NaN"`? `df.loc[(df['HP'] >= 80) & (df['Type 1'] == "Fire") & df['Type 2'].isna()]`

Comment: It works Henry!! Can you please explain what it means this - isna()?

Comment: [Series.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)  "Detect missing values. Return a boolean same-sized object indicating if the values are NA. NA values, such as None or numpy.NaN, gets mapped to True values. Everything else gets mapped to False values. "

Comment: I understand now, Thanks for the help!!